# 128 bit (16bytes) GUID is compressed to how many bit or bytes?

Tags: java, database, compression, uuid, guid

Many articles online are talking about GUID compression from 36 characters to 22 characters using base64. I would like to know how many byte or bit represent exactly the compressed GUID(22character)?
A GUID looks like this c9a646d3-9c61-4cb7-bfcd-ee2522c8f633 - that's 32 hex digits, each encoding 4 bits, so 128 bits in total. A base64 encoding uses 6 bits per symbol, which is easy to achieve with URL safe chars to give a 22 char encoded string. 
How many bit is representing these 22char?

Comment: Are you asking how many bytes a 22 character String uses?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my question.
36character is representing by 128bit. what about 22charaters?

Comment: Providing an example of such articles may be helpful to understand what do you mean

Comment: 22 base64 characters will use 22 bytes if stored as a string, assuming a ASCII or UTF-8 character encoding.

Comment: A GUID looks like this c9a646d3-9c61-4cb7-bfcd-ee2522c8f633 - that's 32 hex digits, each encoding 4 bits, so 128 bits in total

A base64 encoding uses 6 bits per symbol, which is easy to achieve with URL safe chars to give a 22 char encoded string.
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/374025/ShortGUID

Comment: Just a reminder: A GUID & a UUID is actually a **128-bit value**, *not* a string of hex characters. We use 32 hex characters plus 4 hyphens for presentation to humans who otherwise would be unhappy gazing at one hundred and twenty eight `0` & `1` characters on screen. If your database, such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), supports [UUID as a native data-type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) then this Question is moot.

Answer (score 1):

A GUID is functionally very similar to a UUID. It is a 16-byte (128 bit) value. Java's `UUID` class uses two 8-byte `long`s because that is Java's largest primitive type. If you base-64 encode the `long`s, you'll get between 22 and 24 characters, depending on whether the base-64 encoding is padded. Here's some sample code to help you see how this works:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
buf.asLongBuffer()
        .put(uuid.getMostSignificantBits())
        .put(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
String base64Uuid = Base64.getEncoder()
        .withoutPadding()
        .encodeToString(buf.array());
```

The 22 characters will actually use 44 bytes in Java, because Java's `char` is 16 bits. You also have the overhead of the `char[]` array itself and the overhead of the `String` class, so it's even more than that. (Somewhere around 40 bytes, but the exact amount depends on your JVM implementation.)

If you end up using the base-64 encoded string in a URL, the 22 characters will be converted to ASCII, and will then take up 22 bytes, one for each ASCII character.

Comment: Or, rather than strings and base-64, store the UUID in your database as a [native UUID type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html), for only 128 bits (16 octets/bytes).

Comment: Yes, if you are using a database and it has a native UUID type that is preferable to storing them as strings.